# How to send multiple lines of information to telnet/AS400 host and read resulting screen in structured format in Java

Tags: java, command-line, telnet, ibm-midrange, command-line-tool

I am trying to develop a Java program which can send multiple lines of information to a telnet/AS400 host, then receive the resulting screen in a structured format. An example of this may be login credentials (user, pass, library, etc).

With telnet/AS400, when the user connects to the host using command prompt, it displays multiple lines which the input values can be entered on and then sent to the host. 
Like this:

[image: command]

[[image: telnet command interaction]

We see from the example that it is possible to send multiple lines of information to the telnet host using the Windows command line. I want to create a Java program which has the same functionality (sending commands on multiple lines and reading in the screen in a structured format).

I have tried using the Apache Telnet client to read the screen in using Apache Commons IOUtils. Like this:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import org.apache.commons.net.telnet.TelnetClient;
import examples.util.IOUtil;

 // This class requires the IOUtil support class!
public final class Telnet {

public static final void main(String[] args) {
    TelnetClient telnet;

    telnet = new TelnetClient();

    try {
        telnet.connect("hostname", 23);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(1);
    }

 //   IOUtils
    IOUtil.readWrite(telnet.getInputStream(), telnet.getOutputStream(), System.in, System.out);

    try {
        telnet.disconnect();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(1);
    }

    System.exit(0);
}

}
```

which results in reading the screen from the InputStream and then displaying it. Like this

```
[2J [1;22H[1m[0m [1m             Sign On             [0m [2;47H System  . . . . . :   NLSI5D   [3;47H Subsystem . . . . :   QINTER     [4;47H Display . . . . . :   QPADEV000Q [6;16H User  . . . . . . .
```

From this point I cannot choose which line I send information back on. More concretely, if I type in any text and send it back through the console, it will think it is for the username field. I cannot specify any other line or field.

Is it possible to choose what field input line you are sending information on using Java?

The reason it needs to be in Java is so that I can embed it into an Android application.

Comment: You are probably looking for a terminal emulator.  However, a terminal emulator will not know what line is what... it won't know you're entering the username or password.  It just knows how to display text and manage the cursor etc...   There are lots of terminal emulator projects for Java.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish in the end?  Run a command on the host?  Retrieve data from the host?

Comment: I suppose I am trying to send and receive commands from the host. If you could consider sending text a command. For an example, sending the user and password information to the host then retrieving the information on the next page it displays.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably going to want to reference the [TN5250J project](http://tn5250j.sourceforge.net/)

The protocol you need is 5250 over telnet. 5250 is the display protocol used by IBM i. Straight telnet is missing certain control codes, keys, and services provided by 5250. You can make telnet work for simple screens, but most will not. VT-100 is a poor substitute for 5250.

Comment: Do you know where I can find some examples of TN5250J in use?

Comment: No, but it is open source, you should be able to look at the code.

Comment: It seems to be for a desktop application so I am not sure how I could apply this into a mobile app.

Comment: At a minimum you can see how they are handling the 5250 data stream and recreate that in your app.

Comment: Yes okay I can try to do that. Do you have any strategies for breaking a project down? I know Java pretty well but am lacking experience with dissecting projects. My first idea is to try and construct a higher level diagram which encapsulates all the classes, then look deeper into them to see how they are connected and the communication between them. 

I realize this wasn't the original question but I am looking to learn from more experience developers as I am still a student.

Comment: Talk to the developers if you can. Find out what the main classes that parse the 5250 data stream are. Should be able to do this without an IDE because it is on GitHub [here](https://github.com/tn5250j/tn5250j)